# How to highlight contexts/projects in todo.txt?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, to-do

Does anyone use the todo.txt command line interface (todotxt.com)? I would like it so that when I type `todo ls` to show my tasks, it will highlight the +contexts and @projects with colors. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5):

I am not sure when this feature was introduced, but with the current version of `todo.sh`, you can enable the coloring in your config file (normally `todo.cfg`) by setting the variables `COLOR_PROJECT` and `COLOR_CONTEXT` to some value:

```
export COLOR_PROJECT=$LIGHT_BLUE
export COLOR_CONTEXT=$GREEN
```

(for example)

If this is enough for your purpose, you don't have to install an external color filter.

Answer (score 3):

The original color highlighting filter was [posted on the todo.txt mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/todotxt/message/2329). And [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/789447) contains the version I once fixed for Gina, the initiator of todo.txt.

I have also written an extended version, published as [part of my todo.txt-cli-ex extension](https://raw.github.com/inkarkat/todo.txt-cli-ex/master/filter/colorSymbols).

Any of these must be installed in `todo.cfg` via

```
export TODOTXT_FINAL_FILTER=/path/to/colorSymbols
```

Comment: your extension seems not to work with the current todo.sh anymore: {awk: calling undefined function gensub
 input record number 1, file
 source line number 62}

Comment: @david My extension requires GNU awk (`gawk`), because it uses its extensions. That's your problem.